# D3.js pattern not working with arc or donut graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to have an image fill my donut chart, then rotate the image 60 degrees from its center.

I've had success filling a simple shape as a pattern with this method, but the pattern image gets all screwy and repeats itself when applied to a donut chart. The image is 300px x 300px - same size as the svg.  [The final result should look like this](http://www.mikeespo.com/statDonkey/result.png).

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeespo68/qkdcdptu/).

```
imgPath = "http://www.mikeespo.com/statDonkey/inner.png";
w = 300;
h = 300;

passingPercent = 60;
rotateStartPosition = 50;

var myScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

//  MAKES SVG
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "svg_donut")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

//  MAKE DEFS
var defs = d3.select("#svg_donut")
  .append("defs");

// MAKES PATTERN
defs.append('pattern')
  .attr('id', 'pic1')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 300)
  .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
  .append('svg:image')
  .attr('xlink:href', imgPath)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(60 150 150)")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);

//  CREATES VARIABLE *VIS* TO SVG
var vis = d3.select("#svg_donut");

//  DEFINES DONUT GRAPH
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(95)
  .outerRadius(140)
  .startAngle((myScale(0 + rotateStartPosition)))
  .endAngle((myScale(passingPercent + rotateStartPosition)));

//  APPENDS *VIS* TO SVG
vis.append("path")
  .attr("id", "passing")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
  .attr("fill", "url(#pic1)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this works to be honest but when I changed the width and height of the pattern element and removed the patternUnits attribute, I was able to achieve the desired look:

```
defs.append('pattern')
  .attr('id', 'pic1')
  .attr('width', 1)
  .attr('height', 1)
  .append('svg:image')
  .attr('xlink:href', imgPath)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(00 150 150)")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);
```

I don't understand it completely but it has something to do with the coordinate system and the way in which the pattern scales to the object you're applying it to. The width and height aren't defining the size of the image as you might initially think, but the way in which the pattern will map to the new coordinate system of the donut. A width and height of 1 indicates that the pattern will just scale to the width and height of the donut.

Getting my info from here and admittedly not fully grasping it all yet but hopefully this will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

Comment: Thanks for the response, Evan. I made the change, but the image becomes blurred and losses it's resolution. [See an example here](http://www.mikeespo.com/statDonkey/blur.png) There should be a crisp line between the light and dark color.  [Orginal image] (http://www.mikeespo.com/statDonkey/inner.png)

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks again, Evan.